# Server Error in '/Bonobo.Git.Server' Application

Tags: windows-server-2012, bonobo

ставлю bonobogitserver на windows server 2012 r2 делаю установку пошагово согласно инструкции захожу на http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server вижу:

This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://localhost is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

если в настройках iis в aplication pool вместо DefaultAppPool ставлю .net v4.5 то вижу такое:

Server Error in '/Bonobo.Git.Server' Application.

Runtime Error 
  Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

какой может быть следующий шаг? по этим ошибкам не нашел статей ни в рунете ни в инете...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем для того, чтобы Bonobo.Git.Server заработал, нужен asp.net 4.6 об этом собственно говориться на сайте bonobo, сразу не заметил.

при установке asp.net 4.6

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=48130

у меня (как и у многих, судя по форумам) возникла проблема с устрановкой. потребовалось обновление KB3045560

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42334

а чтобы установить, указанное выше обновление, нужно сначала установить KB 2919442

https://www.microsoft.com/ru-RU/download/details.aspx?id=42135

после установок обновления каждый раз нужно перезагружаться.

после этого Bonobo.Git.Server заработал